# Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':compileGroovy'

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to generate a working jar for a mixed Java/Groovy project. This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'

group 'com.victor'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.5.7', ext: 'pom'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev493-1.23.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.18'

}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'com.victor.application.Application'
        )
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew build` from the command line at the project's root folder, I get the following error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':compileGroovy' property 'groovyClasspath' during up-to-date check.
> Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: [/home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.5.7/ce901dd2f4d0cc95123726ad0e9bd900e7a80b32/groovy-all-2.5.7.pom, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.12.1/55819a28fc834c2f2bcf4dcdb278524dc3cf088f/jsoup-1.12.1.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets/v4-rev493-1.23.0/448b4779a44afbee9b068800730e1f8186eb83ad/google-api-services-sheets-v4-rev493-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.23.0/522ea860eb48dee71dfe2c61a1fd09663539f556/google-api-client-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty/1.23.0/e0deaf34371e9ca09f9a04bcbaa854243283cae4/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.18/1afd498e56689f56d2205d16a606e58db20698ac/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.18.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/5af35056b4d257e4b64b9e8069c0746e8b08629f/log4j-1.2.17.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6/1.23.0/7acbddf56c4ad04efc9d3b48fe015e6250241bf0/google-oauth-client-java6-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.23.0/e57ea1e2220bda5a2bd24ff17860212861f3c5cf/google-oauth-client-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/1.23.0/fd6761f4046a8cb0455e6fa5f58e12b061e9826e/google-http-client-jackson2-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/6.1.26/2f546e289fddd5b1fab1d4199fbb6e9ef43ee4b0/jetty-6.1.26.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.18/b631d286463ced7cc42ee2171fe3beaed2836823/slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.23.0/8e86c84ff3c98eca6423e97780325b299133d858/google-http-client-1.23.0.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/40719ea6961c0cb6afaeb6a921eaa1f6afd4cfdf/jsr305-1.3.9.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.1.3/f6c3aed1cdfa21b5c1737c915186ea93a95a58bd/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/e5642fe0399814e1687d55a3862aa5a3417226a9/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mortbay.jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/22bff70037e1e6fa7e6413149489552ee2064702/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/1d7d28fa738bdbfe4fbd895d9486308999bdf440/httpclient-4.0.1.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/e813b8722c387b22e1adccf7914729db09bcb4a9/httpcore-4.0.1.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/5043bfebc3db072ed80fbd362e7caf00e885d8ae/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, /home/victor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/fd32786786e2adb664d5ecc965da47629dca14ba/commons-codec-1.3.jar, /home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/Groovy/ScrapData/build/classes/java/main]
```

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error looks strange and I am unfortunately unable to reproduce it.

One thing that sticks out is the `ext: 'pom'` qualifier on the groovy dependency. Unless you really know what you are doing I would suspect that that is probably not what you want.

That being said, it looks like you are trying to build an executable jar and I figured a working example might help you get unstuck.

The following modified `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'

group 'com.victor'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.7'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev493-1.23.0'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.18'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

shadowJar {
    baseName 'application'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.victor.application.Application'
    }
}
```

uses the shadow jar plugin which is specifically capable of creating fat jars (jars containing all the dependencies for your project).

With the above build file and the following dir structure:

```
.
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── groovy
            └── com
                └── victor
                    └── application
                        └── Application.groovy

6 directories, 2 files
```

where `Application.groovy` contains the following code:

```
package com.victor.application


class Application {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    println "Hello World!"
  }
}
```

the project builds and results in the following output:

```
~> gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-16 02:44:16 UTC
Revision:     a4f3f91a30d4e36d82cc7592c4a0726df52aba0d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.4 x86_64

~>  gradle shadowJar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

~> java -jar build/libs/application-1.0-all.jar
Hello World!
 
~>
```